# what is differences between digraph and subgraph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

what is the difference between **digraph** and **subgraph** in discrete-mathematics. Any one explain the example of these graphs.

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A digraph is just a graph whose edges are directed (i.e, they point from one vertex to another). A subgraph $H$ is a piece of a larger graph $G$, in the sense that every edge of $H$ is an edge in $G$, and similarly every vertex of $H$ is a vertex of $G$. They aren't really related, unless you have a subgraph of a digraph, which itself would be a digraph.

Comment: thanks, but i need some examples of these two graphs

Comment: I'll point you to the comment posted above by J W then, where he lists the wikipedia links. They will have much better examples than I can give